don't received my token to binance
I transferred Grass Crypto, to my Solana address, I thought that the amount is sent, when not I did not receive my token on my binance, on phantom, I have confirmation that The token we were sending to Binance, and on Solscan the transaction is confirmed to send, when I contacted Binance he told me that he does not take care of the token. So I ask for the reimbursement of my token on Phantom. Is it possible?



